# Sort a Nodelist by attribute nodeValue

Tags: javascript

Lets say I have a nodelist

```
NodeList(5) [div.card, div.card, div.card, div.card, div.card]
0    :    div.card
1    :    div.card
2    :    div.card
3    :    div.card
4    :    div.card
length    :    5
__proto__    :    NodeList
```

I would like to sort according to that div's data-attribute called **data-start** using a compare function

```
var cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card');
Array.from(cards).sort( function(a,b){
    let a = a.attributes[2].nodeValue; 
    let b = b.attributes[2].nodeValue;

    return a - b;

}).forEach(el => {
    document.querySelector('.right3').appendChild(el);
});
```

However I am continuing to get the Elements ordered not by their data attribute value which is in my case an ISOString [ex. "2018-01-08T20:39:00Z"].

View JsFiddle Here!
[Js Fiddle containing basic html, css](https://jsfiddle.net/akinhwan/sd41k6mj/)

Comment: Please provide a runnable [mcve]

Comment: Do you have all the `data-start` attribute values? Supplying those would help.

Comment: give me one moment I will edit my post with a jsfiddle I apologize for being unclear

Comment: Are you going for ascending or descending order?

Comment: Well I figured I could just swap `sort()` with `reverse()` if I wanted later? But to answer your question, I was going for reverse Chronological (more recent start time first)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you please try this

```
var cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card');
Array.from(cards).sort( function(a,b){
    a = new Date(a.attributes[2].nodeValue).valueOf() 
    b = new Date(b.attributes[2].nodeValue).valueOf()

    return a - b;

}).forEach(el => {
    document.querySelector('.right3').appendChild(el);
});
```

The issue was you're comparing two strings which results in `NaN` (not a number). This converts the dates to unix time stamps, which is just a number, then compares them instead.

Example based on your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sd41k6mj/4/

Comment: Thanks Noah! I tried this in my console, and got the following error
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'a' has already been declared`

but when I changed let => to var, it worked!!!
I see now that your answer actually didn't include neither let nor var.

Comment: @AkinHwan I updated the answer with a fix for that too. Must remove `let`.